# Share variables between projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have a solution and two projects in it. I want to share variables from project1 to project2 and viceversa. How can i do that?
Maybe with a static class but I don't know how can handle it.

Comment: define 'variables' - do you mean constants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want share constants, you can add a Shared Project and reference the Shared Project into project1 and project2. The code in the Shared Project (a static class with constants members) is linked into other projects :

```
public static class Constants
{
    const string AppName = "AppName";
    const string AppUrl = "http://localhost:1234/myurl";
    const int SomethingCount = 3;
}
```

If you want share runtime variables (with dynamic values), you can add a Class Library or a PCL and reference it into project1 and project2. The code in the Class Library will be compiled in a DLL and shared between other projects. You can create a class with static members and share your runtime variables by this way :

```
public static class RuntimeValues
{
    public static string AppName { get; set; }
    public static string AppUrl { get; set; }
    public static int SomethingCount { get; set; }
}
```

In your project1 and project2, you can do something like :

```
var appName = Constants.AppName;
```

Or :

```
RuntimeValues.AppName = "AppName";
var appName = RuntimeValues.AppName;
```

Comment: but for example if project1 at runtime executes `RuntimeValues.AppName = "MyApp";` after inside project2 what is the value of RuntimeValues.AppName ?

Comment: @ClaudioCayoCastagnetti i know its too late but were you able to find anything for your use case I'm kind of into same situation.

Comment: If project1 and project2 are two consoleapp, there is one process per project at runtime, so this is not the way to share some data between your N project.
You should use persistent store (file), a server, or a communication protocol between your N process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple objects looking for the same data, and that data needs to be constrained to a single instance, then a [Singleton](http://thesharp.ninja/one-class-to-rule-them-all-a-look-at-singletons-in-c/) is for you.

```
public class AppSingleton
{
// Private static reference to the long instance of this
// Singleton.  
private static readonly AppSingleton _instance = new AppSingleton();

// Current state of the application.
private State _state = State.Start;

public State State => _state;

// Private constructor ensures that only the Singleton
// can create new instances.
private AppSingleton() { }

public AppSingleton Instance => _instance;
}
```